# Populate UICollectionViewCell with Years and Months

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need to populate the cells of a `UICollectionView` with a list of years from **2000** to **2050**.

Each cell must contain one month of the year up to the twelfth month and then start again with a new year.

Example 12 cells for the year 2000, another 12 cells for the year 2001 etc ...

[image]

What is the best way to go with swift 5?

Comment: Hi @kAiN, why you need to do this? The layout must need to be that way? You couldnt find any POD to do that for you?

Comment: @DanielArantesLoverde 
Hi ... yes I need this type of layout for a horizontal calendar

Comment: Have a look at [enumerateDates(startingAfter:matching:options:using:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1413938-enumeratedates) of `Calendar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set cell count as (2050-2000)*12

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return (2050-2000)*12
}
```

then define start year variable and months name array

```
var year:Int = 2000
let months:[String] = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"]
```

now you can add data to collectionview cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    //define cell

    cell.lblYear.text = "\(year+indexPath.row.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 12).quotient)"
    cell.lblMonth.text = months[indexPath.row % 12]



    return cell
}
```

Comment: nice answer 

Comment: ohh! Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: I'm having some problems when I scroll between the cells .. It seems that the years don't keep a logical thread ... When I scroll the collectionView it loses the calculation of the years .. If I scroll only 4 cells and then I go back to the first year, the year has changed

Comment: I keep having the same problem :(

Comment: I think the problem is here `if indexPath.item % 12 == 0 { startYear += 1 }`

Comment: It works now ... thank you very much! you have been very kind